# Ruby пишет лишний символ

Tags: ruby, utf-8

Добрый день. 
Если с помощью read или readline прочитать файл в кодировке utf8(в файле русский текст), то появляется лишний символ - ? вначале первой стоки.
Например, такой файл:
Первая строка.
Вторая строка.

open("r:utf-8") - открываю так, затем делаем read(), результат будет такой:
?Первая строка.
Вторая строка.
Почему это происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего это происходит из-за наличия [BOM](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) в начале файла. Если сохранить файл, например, блокнотом в UTF-8, то он сохранит его с BOM. Вы можете открыть файл каким-нибудь редактором, в котором можно выбирать кодировку и перевести файл в UTF-8 without BOM.

Или средствами Ruby пропускать первый символ (его значение `U+FEFF`).

Comment: спасибо, проблема решилась